# uWSGI [+ nginx] file descriptor error (no such file or directory)

Tags: python, uwsgi

I'm trying to configure uWSGI for a Django project. Unfortunately when I run the uwsgi executable it fails with a weird error:

```
$ bin/uwsgi -s sock/uwsgi.sock --chdir testit --vacuum \
--env DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=testit.testit.settings --wsgi-file testit/wsgi.py --master
*** Starting uWSGI 1.2.3 (32bit) on [Mon Jun  4 17:14:52 2012] ***
compiled with version: 4.7.0 20120414 (prerelease) on 04 June 2012 16:20:49
detected number of CPU cores: 2
current working directory: /home/miki/sites/testit
detected binary path: /home/miki/sites/testit/bin/uwsgi
your memory page size is 4096 bytes
detected max file descriptor number: 1024
lock engine: pthread robust mutexes
bind(): No such file or directory [socket.c line 107]
```

I haven't the foggiest idea of what to do... I tried with `ulimit` and it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the `chdir` command is executed before anything else, so it can't find the files if you use relative paths. Try using the full path in your arguments:

```
bin/uwsgi -s $PWD/sock/uwsgi.sock --chdir testit --vacuum \
--env DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=testit.testit.settings \
--wsgi-file $PWD/testit/wsgi.py --master
```

Comment: Yep! You are right. I didn't know that `--chdir` is executed before everything else.